# Tableview not reloading after unwind from segue in Swift 2

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

I have a working table populating data from an array declared as

```
var tableData:[AnyObject] = []
```

Here is the unwind function

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if(segue.sourceViewController .isKindOfClass(AddNewsViewController))
        {
            let data:AddNewsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as! AddNewsViewController
            let newscontent = data.contentView.text
            let newstitle = data.contentView.text
            let author = data.contentView.author
            let dateposted = data.contentView.dateposted
            let icon = data.contentView.icon
            let location = data.contentView.location
            let description = data.contentView.description

            self.tableData.append(
                [
                    "title":newstitle,
                    "author":author,
                    "dateposted":date,
                    "icon":envelope,
                    "location":location,
                    "description":description
                ]
            )
            self.newsTable.reloadData()
            print(self.tableData)
        }
    }
```

the log returns the array with the recently appended data, but the tableview is not reloading with the new details.

Comment: Try reloading the data in `viewDidAppear` rather than in `unwindToVC`

Comment: @TheBeanstalk, that actually works.  You should have this as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `newsTable.reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear` rather than in `unwindToVC`. According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData):

> For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible.

When `unwindToVC` gets called none of the rows are visible yet.